# "Conflicting files" and that file is not part of my Release branch

Tags: git, github

Today we have 2 different release. 
Ex: Release 1 is for sales and Release 2 is for Purchase
Upon successful technical deployment in PROD, we need to merge this two changes to master.
Release 1 to Master was successful. But, Release 2 to Master was not successful and showing as "Conflicting files" and this file is not part of Release 2 and that file is part of Release 1.

Please advise how can I merge back Release 2 to master.

Thanks
RG